Issues with running dlib on a MacBook with an M2 chip
I'm having issues running dlib on my MacOS error in my code). When I check the terminal, it says that dlib is already installed as well as cmake. Yet, when I import it in a script, it doesn't work. It feels like I've tried everything to install dlib but nothing has worked. Any ideas?
I've already tried most documentation online for installing and running dlib on MacBook but am still having issues.
 ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/an aconda3/envs/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture ( have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/0S/opt/anaconda3/envs/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_d lib orbindl.covthon-310-darwin.sor (no such file). lib_pybind11. cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/envs/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))
`

How exactly did you install dlib? you installed a dlib with intel native libraries, and you need arm native libraries.
